# Proof/Disproof - Exist $A_{nxn}$ so all $b \in R^n$ the linear system $Ax=b$ has infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this problem :

Proof/Disproof - Exist $A_{nxn}$  so all $b \in R^n$ the linear system $Ax=b$ has infinite solutions.

I think its wrong, but I don't know how to proof it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel If $b\ne 0$, then $A=0$ does not work.

Comment: Notice that if for every $b$, exists $x$ s.t. $Ax=b$ then $A$ is surjective, so $A$ has a right inverse. But the right inverse is equal to the left inverse.

Comment: Daniel solved the problem: $A$ cannot exist.

Comment: @Daniel Great solution Daniel, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

In particular: we note that the equation $Ax = 0$ can only have infinitely many solutions if $A$ has a non-trivial kernel (null-space).  That is, the kernel has dimension at least $1$.

However, if $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions, then the image of $A$ is all of $\Bbb R^n$, so that the rank of $A$ is $n$.

By the rank-nullity theorem, these statements cannot be simultaneously true.